# Is there any way of implementing the insert method for a standards-compliant vector?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Firstly, assume `A` is a type with:

- A potentially throwing copy constructor/assignment operator.
- No move constructor/assignment.

This is a common example of a C++03 RAII type. Now let me cite the C++14 standard (snipped irrelevant parts):

> #### §23.2.1 General container requirements
>
> <sup>11</sup> Unless otherwise specified (see ... and 23.3.6.5) all container types defined in this
>   Clause meet the following additional requirements:
>
> - if an exception is thrown by an `insert()` or `emplace()` function while inserting a single element, that function has no effects.
>
> #### §23.3.6.5  `vector` modifiers
>
> ```
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, const T& x);
> ...
> ```
>
> <sup>1</sup> *Remarks:* Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of `T` or by any `InputIterator` operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown while inserting a single element at the end and `T` is `CopyInsertable` or `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is `true`, there are no effects. Otherwise, if an exception is thrown by the move constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`, the effects are unspecified.
>
> <sup>2</sup> *Complexity:* The complexity is linear in the number of elements inserted plus the distance to the end
>   of the vector.

Now consider this:

```
std::vector<A> v(5);
v.reserve(10);
v.insert(begin() + 2, A());
```

Clearly we're inserting a single element, so §23.2.1 - 11 applies and either the operation succeeds or `v` is unchanged. §23.3.6.5 doesn't change anything about this. The exception is thrown by the copy constructor. We are not inserting at the end. The move constructor is not used.

But now consider this possible scenario during the implementation of insert **assuming no reallocation happens**:

```
01234_____ initial state
0123_4____ making space by copying
012_34____ continued
012?34____ continued, but copy operation threw
```

At this point all future copy operations could throw, making it impossible to restore the state as required. Oops.

I can't see any implementation without reallocation that enables strong exception safety. This means that any implementation must always reallocate when inserting a type without a move constructor and a throwing copy constructor in the middle. However:

1. `insert(pos, value)` becomes unbearably slow due to constant reallocations.
2. The complexity requirement isn't met (reallocation always requires `n` operations).
3. It could be argued that *"Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity."* implies that no reallocation is allowed if the new size is not greater than the old capacity.

   To support this, consider that if an implementation may reallocate anytime, the user has no way of knowing. This makes the guarantee about preserving iterators (*"If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid."*) useless information, and makes you wonder why both sentences were inserted into the standard in the first place.

1 & 2 are pretty damning observations, but if 3 is true then it's (as far as I can see) plain impossible to be compliant with the standard.

So, is there any way of implementing the insert method for a standards-compliant vector? Or is this a standard defect?

---

A demonstration of this issue can be seen here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afd2e838c34c8fcc

Comment: "Making space by copying" shouldn't this result in `012344_____`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your concern. Do you think §23.3.6.5 implies that this operation `v.insert(begin() + 2, A());` provides the strong exception safety guarantee?

Comment: @dyp In an efficient implementation, yes, but for educational clarity I notated it as if you'd destruct the original value after copying.

Comment: @dyp I'm under the impression §23.2.1 - 11 implies that, and that §23.3.6.5 does not refute that.

Comment: I agree with Columbo that §23.3.6.5 is probably meant to completely replace §23.2.1/11 for `insert`. But that seems to be the crucial point.

Comment: @dyp That's weird though, as generally the standard is built up as a layers of specified behaviours, exceptions to those default behaviours and letting the rest be undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as my interpretation of the standard goes, here "Unless otherwise specified" means that once anything regarding exceptions is specified for `insert` in a corresponding clause for a particular container, the bullet point of the list in §23.2.1 is not applying anymore.

> If an exception is thrown **other than by the copy constructor** [..]
>   of `T` [..] there are no effects.

The opposite is indicated: When an exception is thrown by the copy constructor of `T` there is no guarantee that the call won't have any effects. The requirement that

> if an exception is thrown by an `insert()` or `emplace()` function while inserting a single element, that function has no effects

is not applicable: §23.3.6.5 specifies "otherwise".

Comment: It does seem that this is the intended interpretation. It's counter-intuitive though, as generally the standard is built up as some "default behaviour", piling on exceptions afterwards. Rarely are previously established rules totally disregarded.

Comment: The crucial point is that _"Unless otherwise specified"_ is ambiguous. It's possible (as I did in my question) to argue that §23.3.6.5 specifies nothing regarding `std::vector<A>`.

Comment: @orlp ... and if it doesn't specify anything regarding `vector<A>`, then the effects are unspecified? :P

Comment: No, if §23.3.6.5 specifies nothing, _"Unless otherwise specified"_ can be disregarded, and thus §23.2.1 - 11 would apply.

Comment: @orlp Nothing regarding **that particular type**. But it does specify **something**, and that is why *"Unless otherwise specified"* **cannot** be disregarded.

Comment: I agree with @orlp's interpretation. "Nothing regarding **that particular type**" is not something you can infer from any part of the standard. This answer is very likely the intended interpretation, but just does not logically follow from the wording in the standard. Taken even further, your reading suggests that "Unless otherwise specified ... all container types defined in this Clause meet the following additional requirements:" means that *none* of the following requirements apply to `vector<T>`, even though I'm sure you'll agree that 11.4 should.

Comment: @hvd When the subject covered in a particular bullet point is specified otherwise for a container then that bullet point (and not the others) is to be ignored. All other bullet points are orthogonal and not affected. Apart from that my answer clearly states that "[…] the bullet point of the list in §23.2.1 is not applying anymore." Not the list itself.

Comment: @Columbo But the only text that says that the list applies is the text immediately above the list, which covers *all* items in the list in a single sentence, and says that that single sentence applies "unless otherwise specified". (Again, that's clearly not how it's meant to be read, but based on what it actually says, it's just as legitimate an interpretation as yours, IMO.)

Comment: @hvd Yes, I believe you're correct. Do you think this requires a DR?

Comment: @Columbo There has been at least one person (the OP) who was genuinely confused by the current wording, and IMO that confusion is *not* caused by a lack of understanding of the OP, but by unclear wording in the standard, so yes, I think it would be better if the standard got changed to be clearer.

Comment: @Columbo: The `vector::insert` part of the standard specifically says this: "If an exception is thrown while inserting a single element at the end and T is CopyInsertable or is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value is true, there are no effects.".  That makes the point about the copy constructor irrelevant.

Comment: @Columbo: Furthermore, this reasoning is wrong. The statement is not saying that if X *doesn't apply*, then all bets are off. The statement is saying that if X applies, then there are no effect. That sentence says *nothing* about what happens if X doesn't apply, so subsequent sentences can apply to that scenario. Which is what the next sentence is about.